# Extracting a vector element every timestep as the simulation runs

Tags: simulink

I have a 1D vector (y) in the workspace that has elements in it. I want these elements to amplify the magnitude of a sine-wave (through a multiplication box). How do I tell simulink to extract only one element on every timestep for the multiplication?

[image: see attached]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable used in the `From Workspace` block must have a specific format.  Press the `Help` button on the block for a discussion of those formats.

All of them require a time vector to be specified in addition to the signal value.  For instance,

```
t = 0:0.1:10;
u = rand(size(t));
tu = [t(:) u(:)];
```

would create a suitable input that makes the block output a random value, with the value changing every 0.1s.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but in case it might help others. A solution that I found for a problem like this was using the "Signal From Workspace" block, which is different from the "From Workspace" block. With the former, you don't need a time vector. Just put the vector name you need from workspace and set the sample time. There is also the option to read the vector repeatedly.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34680065)